# c# передача аргумента из класса в форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Существует метод в классе, в котором выполняется зацикленный код, в конце которого присваивается значение некоторой переменной. Как это значение передать в форму в TextBox?

Метод в классе:

```
public static void Class()
{
    while (Variable.armor_is == true)
    {
        //какой-то код выше
        Variable.armor_value = 150; //это значение нужно передать в форму в TextBox
    }
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Я предлагаю это winforms?

Comment: Да, это WindowsForms

Comment: myform.mytextbox.Text =

Comment: Form1.ArmorLabel.Text = Variable.armor_value.ToString(); - пишу это в цикле, но отладчик пишет "Для нестатического поля, метода свойства "..." требуется ссылка на объект"

Comment: Да, как то так.

Comment: Зачем изменять это в цикле

Comment: т.к. данная переменная отображает значение брони персонажа и нужно постоянно изменять её, когда на персонажа действует яд

Comment: И да статично у классу вы должны передать свой Text box чтобы он менял его

Comment: Иначе он не будет статичным

Comment: Для начала сделайте метод нестатическим, экземплярным. Потому что со статическими членами обычно труднее работать: возникают сложности при инъекции зависимостей, проблемы при модульном тестировании (сложно замокать) и пр.

Answer (score 0):

Передайте свой TextBox статичному методу и пусть он меняется его свойства.

```
public static void Class(TextBox txt)
{
    while (Variable.armor_is == true)
    {
        //какой-то код выше
        Variable.armor_value = 150; //это значение нужно передать в форму в TextBox
        txt.Text = Variable.armor_value.ToString();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Даже если передать тектбокс

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь ещё способ? т.к. активация этого метода происходит через Thread

Comment: С потоками нужно играть осторожно. Ваша форма должна смотреть на результат который записан где-то.

Comment: Поймите нииваш поток ни форма не предполагает существования друг друга

Comment: Тут без потоков не обойтись, тк очень много действий одновременно выполняется. Без этого производительность просто будет нулевая. Может как-то через наследование или что-нибудь такое можно сделать?

Comment: Что нибудь это к шаманам а вам нужно создать callback и передать его который будет вызываться из другого потока. Как то так

Comment: @Frehzy - То, что этот метод запускается в отдельном потоке - критически важная информация. И это обязательно должно быть написано в вопросе. Так что отредактируйте вопрос. И покажите код, как именно вызываете этот метод.